# Can't concatenate with GLOB function?

Tags: concatenation, glob

I am working with php and trying to concatenate within the GLOB function. I can't seem to get it to work. My code is as follows:

```
$dir = "$images/*";
$images = glob( $dir . "{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE );
```

This does work:

```
$images = glob( "images/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

For perspective, I am using the glob function to post images to a webpage from within a directory "images." What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to concatenate within glob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a php `$` variable symbol hiding out in your `$dir` variable:

```
$dir = "$images/*";
```

In PHP, the dollar sign within double quotes will be interpreted as a proper PHP variable.  So `$images/*` will get interpreted as the variable `$images` plus the string `/*`.

Probably what you're looking for instead is this:

```
$dir = "images/*";
```

As a general habit, I prefer single quotes in PHP where possible, as it tends to surface this kind of easily-masked error more efficiently, because the single quoted `$` symbol will be interpreted as a string.